# JQuery UI DatePicker with disabled field

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<input type="text" value="06-Jul-2011" propertyname="ChildOptionComponent.FirstRollDate" onchange="parseAndSetDt(this); " name="ChildOptionComponent_FirstRollDate" id="ChildOptionComponent_FirstRollDate" disabled="disabled" datatype="Date" class="economicTextBox hasDatepicker">
```

Problem here is, the field is disabled (greyed out to the user), but you can still open the Date Picker and set the date, you just can't manually modify the date field yourself.

How can we make the Date Picker unable to open when the field is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable datepicker on a field you need to use the destroy or disable properties

[DatePicker Options](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#options)

Example:

```
someinput.disabled = true

$('select that input').datePicker('disable');

// or
$('select that input').datePicker('destroy');
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using hasDatepicker to convert the text boxes to datepicker.

You can just pick/select the textboxes that have the hasDatepicker class and are not disabled and them convert them to date pickers.

So in the code where you are using the selector try this:

```
$(".hasDatepicker:not(:disabled)").datepicker(..options..);
```